# MySql Query for one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql

Facing issue in mysql query, tried with mysql join but not getting expected output.

I want all class, all student record with total ratingscore.Each Class has Many Student. Student has Many or none scholarship

### Class table looks like this

```
+---------------------+
|   id      classname |
+---------------------+
|   1            10   |
|   2            11   |
|   3            12   |
+---------------------+
```

### Student table looks like, classid is foreign key

```
+------------------------------------+
|   id     classid       studentname |
+------------------------------------+
|   1        1            xembine    |
|   2        1            denial     |
|   3        2            suzone     |
|   4        3            rosh       |
|   5        2            broad      |
|   6        1            bell       |
|   7        3            martin     |
|   8        1            jroff      |
+------------------------------------+
```

### rating table looks like, studentid is foreign key

```
+------------------------------------+
|   id      studentid    ratingscore |
+------------------------------------+
|   1           1         4000       |
|   2           1         10000      |
|   3           5         20000      |
|   4           2         1000       |
|   5           6         2222       |
|   6           1         5000       |
|   7           6         12000      |
|   8           3         3800       |
|   9           5         7500       |
+------------------------------------+
```

Here : No student from class 3, got any ratingscore yet.so need that student has zero ratingscore.

### Expected Output:-

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|   studentname  studentid  classid   classname   ratingscore |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|     xembine       1         1           10         19000    |
|     denial        2         1           10          1000    |
|     suzone        3         2           11          3800    |
|     rosh          4         3           12            0     |
|     broad         5         2           11          27500   |
|     bell          6         1           10          2222    |
|     martin        7         3           12            0     |
|     jroff         8         1           10            0     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Where is your proposed query? We're not going to do it for you. But you need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if you want to get an empty row when there's no match.

Comment: So, Where Is Your **Tried** Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s.studentname, s.id as studentid,s.classid,c.classname,sum(ifnull(r.ratingscore,0)) as ratingscore from student s
join class c on c.id=s.classid
left outer join rating r on r.studentid=s.id
group by s.studentname,r.studentid,s.classid,c.classname
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

```
SELECT s.studentname,  s.studentid, c.classid, c.classname, SUM(r.ratingscore)
  FROM student as s
INNER JOIN class c on c.classid = s.classid
LEFT OUTER JOIN ratingscore rs ON s.studentid = rs.studentid
GROUP BY s.studentname,  s.studentid, c.classid, c.classname
ORDER BY s.studentid
```

If there is student without class, you have to change inner join to left outer join

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.studentname AS studentname,  s.id AS studentid, c.id AS classid, c.classname AS classname, SUM(r.ratingscore) AS ratingscore
FROM student AS s
INNER JOIN class AS c ON c.id = s.classid
LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.studentid = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.id
```